# Javascript regex pattern to match for Function keys from F1-F12 using pattern test function

Tags: javascript

Javascript regex pattern to match for Function keys from F1-F12 using pattern test function

I tried below but gives false as output, excepted is true

```
let text = "F11";
let pattern = /^[F][1-12]$/;
let result = pattern.test(text); console.log(result);
```

Comment: `/^F(?:\d|1[012])$/`

Comment: it passes F0 as true as well,  just need to pass F1-F12

Comment: True, my bad, it's `[1-9]` instead of `\d`, so `/^F(?:[1-9]|1[012])$/`. Good you are testing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression matches F1-F12: `/^F[1-9](?:(?<=1)(?:0|1|2))?$/`:

```js
let re = /^F[1-9](?:(?<=1)(?:0|1|2))?$/;

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  let text = `F${i}`;
  console.log(`${text}: ${re.test(text)}`);
}
```

To break it down:

- `^` matches the start of input; it will only match if it is at the beginning
- `F` matches a literal `'F'`
- `[1-9]` matches a character between 1 and 9
- `(?:(?<=1)(?:0|1|2))` is where it matches 11 and 12

  - `(?<=1)(?:0|1|2))` is a lookbehind assertion: it will only match the second part if the first is true

    - `(?:0|1|2)` matches the 0, 1, or 2 for the 10-12